# How can I add a searchview to my Android app?

Tags: android, search

I want to add a searchview to my Android app but I can't understand the documentation. I have added

```
<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:includeInGlobalSearch="true"
       android:searchSuggestAuthority="dictionary"
       android:searchSuggestIntentAction="android.intent.action.VIEW">
</searchable>
```

to my xml and `<intent-filter>`

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" /
</intent-filter>
<meta-data android:name="android.app.searchable" android:resource="@xml/searchable" />
```

to my manifest. But where should the `provider`-tag go? i get a error inflating class exception when running the app. 
Anyone know of a good tutorial? THanks!

Answer (score 8):

This answer is quite later, but as I can see, other answers are only *answer-links*. Then, I will try to provide some explainations with short example code.
Adding a `SearchView` is described in the [Documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html#SearchableConfiguration), and it's quite easy to follow the steps. As we can read on [Create a Search Interface](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html#SearchableActivity) topic:

> The`<intent-filter>`does not need a`<category>`with the **DEFAULT** value (which you usually see in`<activity>`elements), because the system delivers the **ACTION_SEARCH** intent explicitly to your searchable activity, using its component name.

Then, your manifest become:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
</intent-filter>  
<meta-data android:name="android.app.searchable"
    android:resource="@xml/my_searchable_layout"/>
```

*"Traditionally, your search results should be presented in a ListView, so you might want your searchable activity to extend ListActivity"* - still from Docs. So your `SearchActivity` might be:

```
public class SearchActivity extends ListActivity { }
```

*"When the user executes a search from the search dialog or a search widget, the system creates an Intent and stores the user query in it. The system then starts the activity that you've declared to handle searches (the "searchable activity") and delivers it the intent"*. You need to get the query search from the search dialog or widget by using an `Intent` in `onCreate` method:

```
// Get the intent, verify the action and get the query
Intent intent = getIntent();
if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {
    // Receive the query
    String query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
    // Search method..
    doMySearch(query);
}
```

`doMySearch()` can be an `AsyncTask`, a new `Thread`.. connected to a `SQLite DataBase`, a `SharedPreference`, whatever.. *"The process of storing and searching your data is unique to your application"*. This being said, you should create an `Adapter` to provide your results in the list.

Here is a short `ListActivity` example for `SearchActivity` using an asynctask to populate a list:

```
public class SearchActivity extends ListActivity {
    // Create an array
    String[] values;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.list_activity_layout);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            String query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
            // At the end of doMySearch(), you can populate 
            // a String Array as resultStringArray[] and set the Adapter
            doMySearch(query);
        }
    }

    class doMySearch extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            // Connect to a SQLite DataBase, do some stuff..
            // Populate the Array, and return a succeed message
            // As String succeed = "Loaded";
            return succeed;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            if(result.equals("Loaded") {
                 // You can create and populate an Adapter
                 ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                            SearchActivity.this,
                            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values);
                 setListAdapter(adapter);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, I prefer to use a `SearchView` widget with the *AppCompat* or *ActionBarSherlock* and it describes [at the end](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html#UsingSearchWidget) of the topic. It's I think more adapted since you asked your question *(3 years ago ^^)*. So, to do:

```
// Example with AppCompat
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the options menu
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.options_menu, menu);
    MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search);
    // Get the SearchView and set the searchable configuration
    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem);
    // Assumes current activity is the searchable activity
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
    searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(true); // Iconify the widget
    return true;
}
```

And perform a `startActivity()` method to pass the query to `SearchActivity` in `onOptionsItemSelected` method. Then, you will just to add this search item into your menu as follows (don't forget the [custom prefix](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18099372/2668136)) like you can see on [Adding an Action View](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#ActionView):

```
<item android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:title="@string/action_search"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
    yourapp:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"
    yourapp:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView" />
```

In [sample Docs](http://developer.android.com/samples/index.html), you have the **Searchable Dictionary** demo which contains a `ListView` and provide a full demo of connecting `SQLite DataBase` via an `Adapter`.
Voila! I hope you found the solution yet and this post will help someone which want the same.

Comment: Please stop posting incorrect/incomplete Android documentation links. There are too many of them, and linking to generic Samples doesn't help at all. As bad as pointing to `http://developers.android.com`. On top of that, I can think of a lot of people who have been confused by their layout of example code. Which keeps shifting.

Comment: Dear @Sonny, I agree for the Samples docs at the end but I didn't find the *Searchable Dictionary* at this time (I'll change that later). However, *"incorrect/incomplete"* links? Hum, sorry, but I don't see the same. This answer is, as I said: *"to provide some explainations with short example code"* - not the complete Android Documentation! These links are **related to** what I wrote. You don't think it's good? Then, edit it and suggest your way!

Comment: please accept my apologies. I will make my recommendations via edits--that said, there is no such sample in the android site now. I caught your answer in a fit of trying to get my Search to work (2+ days and counting), and I am sorry I was rude. That said, I would say that the Android documentation is very nice in parts, and very disorganized in parts. (E.g., should a beginning developer focus on API guides or Training? Or both? They lead you down different paths. What's the difference between the two? Is the documentations updated to realize the bugs? E.g., Date/TimePickerDialog.