# Action Bar not showing action view icons

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-support-library, android-actionbar-compat

I'm using the new Action Bar Support and all my action views are shown in overflow and not as icons in the bar. My app is for 7+ API.

HomeActivity:

```
public class HomeActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setTitle(R.string.app_name);
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.home, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

home.xml

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:showAsAction="never"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_browse"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:showAsAction="never"
    android:title="@string/title_activity_browse"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"
    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"
    android:title="@string/text_search"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_scan"
    android:icon="@drawable/action_scan"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="@string/title_activity_browse"/>
```

I'm deploying on Nexus 7 with 4.3 and on LGP500 with 2.3.3 and no icons. I've also added android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar" on the manifest and my project is correctly referencing android-support-v7-appcompat as described in the official doc.

Comment: possible duplicate of [android.support.v7 with \`ActionBarActivity\` no menu shows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17881547/android-support-v7-with-actionbaractivity-no-menu-shows)

Answer (score 82, accepted):

you have to define your `menu` resource files with also the attributes for the support library.

To implement the back support it reads them instead of the ones defined in older Android version.

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:yourapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:showAsAction="never"
    yourapp:showAsAction="never"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_browse"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:showAsAction="never"
    yourapp:showAsAction="never"
    android:title="@string/title_activity_browse"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"
    yourapp:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"
    yourapp:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
    android:title="@string/text_search"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_scan"
    android:icon="@drawable/action_scan"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    yourapp:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="@string/title_activity_browse"/>

</menu>
```

**NB**
remeber that for **the SearchView class changed**. it's now used the one from the support library so you also have to **update your code in the onCreateOptionsMenu()**

**EDIT:**
[here](http://www.grokkingandroid.com/migrating-actionbarsherlock-actionbarcompat/) is a pretty good tutorial on how to migrate from ActionBarSherlok to AppCompat

Comment: Yeah, it works fine except for the search view: the icon is displayed correctly but nothing happens if a click on it...anyway I'm really having hard times getting the point here, is it a sort of default schema overriding? Why i didn't found any documentation about it? :(

Comment: yes, it is. Basically to be able to implement the back support they couldn't read the new menu attributes defined only after API 11 ( ? not sure ) so they defined new attributes and they use them.

I'm gonna edit my answear with the correct searchView implamenetation.

Comment: K, marked as answered, can you say anything about search icon issue? EDIT: solved adding custom tag =) Many thanks again.

Comment: I've just noticed that search button works correctly but in logcat i get: "could not find class android.support.v7.widget.SearchView$5...". I don't understand, I've added yourapp:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView" and that class is visible (i.e. via a normal import).

Comment: mh really?! sorry, i can't help you on this right away, that's probably happening also on my app. gonna check.

Comment: sry for the late answear. Are you getting that logcat on a 4.x device?

Comment: Exactly the same problem described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18386739/could-not-find-class-android-support-v7-widget-searchview5 on 2.3.3.

Comment: it's just a guess, but it might be that if you change android:actionViewClass with android.widget.SearchView you won't get that error. But i think that then you'd have to manage the difference by code

Comment: @MarioLenci yourapp:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.Spinner" not working !!!for drop down spinner any idea?

Comment: I'm not sure i understood the problem. anyway at first I'd check the code that initialize the Spinner in the onCreateOptionMenu(...) callback. Honestly i never had to use a spinner into the ActionBar, make sure the code looks like something like here ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8312344/how-to-add-a-dropdown-item-on-the-action-bar ) and then add the appcompat functionalities

Comment: Hey! I understand this is an old question, but I was curious if the double declaration for showAsAction is required? When using the support libraries my phone (4.3) doesn't seem to read the android: tagged one even when "yourapp" is missing.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, anyway the correct way is to declare them both.

Comment: @MarioLenci Could you perhaps link to a resource that would explain why? Sorry if I'm incomprehensible. What I meant is: on my phone which I use for debugging (it uses Android 4.3) it didn't seam to make a difference if the android: namespaced one is declared or not, when using support libraries (hence the myapp namespaced one). I guess what I'm trying to get at is, when/where is the android.showAsAction used if both are declared.

Comment: What is "yourapp" in `yourapp:actionViewClass`. Apparently it is not the package name because I tried 'com.mycompany.myproject` and got nothing.

Comment: It's just an identifier for your custom xml.schema defined at the top of the layout.

Comment: Must both attributes be used at the same time? Those with android prefix AND those with yourapp prefix?

Comment: The ones with yourapp prefix should be enought if you use the AppCompat MenuInflater

Answer (score -1):

A common mistake is forgetting to include the title string in your string.xml file. Make sure you include it for each menu item.

Suppose our menu xml contains the following item :

```
    <item
    android:id="@+id/toggle_action"
    android:orderInCategory="1"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:title="@string/toggle_action"/>
```

If we forget to include the value for the string toggle_action, then the action bar icon will not show.

Go to your strings.xml file and add in the following:

```
    <string name="toggle_action">TOGGLE</string>
```

Comment: Can you be more specific? What "title" string refers to?