# What do these Android logcat warnings mean?

Tags: android, android-studio, logcat, android-support-library

It doesn't seem to impact anything in my app... yet.  I'm using the Android support libraries for the first time (my projects to date have not used support libraries), but this is a new project without much in the way of customization yet. Activities were generated by Android Studio 0.9.2 and implement Navigation Drawer.

Running this on a Verizon Samsung Galaxy SIII running Android 4.4.2. Project is set to minSDK of 15 and targeted SDK of 21.

```
11-21 10:31:18.204    7095-7095/com.myapp.debug I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.view.ViewGroup.onNestedScrollAccepted, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onNestedScrollAccepted
11-21 10:31:18.204    7095-7095/com.myapp.debug W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 11400: Landroid/view/ViewGroup;.onNestedScrollAccepted (Landroid/view/View;Landroid/view/View;I)V
11-21 10:31:18.204    7095-7095/com.myapp.debug D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0000
11-21 10:31:18.204    7095-7095/com.myapp.debug I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.view.ViewGroup.onStopNestedScroll, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onStopNestedScroll
11-21 10:31:18.204    7095-7095/com.myapp.debug W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 11406: Landroid/view/ViewGroup;.onStopNestedScroll (Landroid/view/View;)V
11-21 10:31:18.204    7095-7095/com.myapp.debug D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0000
11-21 10:31:18.204    7095-7095/com.myapp.debug I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.stopNestedScroll, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.setHideOnContentScrollEnabled
11-21 10:31:18.204    7095-7095/com.myapp.debug W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 8977: Landroid/support/v7/internal/widget/ActionBarOverlayLayout;.stopNestedScroll ()V
11-21 10:31:18.204    7095-7095/com.myapp.debug D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x000e
11-21 10:31:18.234    7095-7095/com.myapp.debug I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getChangingConfigurations, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintTypedArray.getChangingConfigurations
11-21 10:31:18.234    7095-7095/com.myapp.debug W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 368: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getChangingConfigurations ()I
11-21 10:31:18.234    7095-7095/com.myapp.debug D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
11-21 10:31:18.234    7095-7095/com.myapp.debug I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getType, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintTypedArray.getType
11-21 10:31:18.234    7095-7095/com.myapp.debug W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 390: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getType (I)I
11-21 10:31:18.234    7095-7095/com.myapp.debug D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
```

If I'm guessing (and I am), I'm missing a library that android.support.v7 requires.  But I have no idea what or where to find it.

Comment: Does your action bar overlap the scroller?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Could not find class 'android.support.v7.widget.SearchView$5'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18386739/could-not-find-class-android-support-v7-widget-searchview5)

Comment: @Evan037 - It doesn't appear so. I have barely started working this project - I just added a Navigation Drawer activity through Android Studio so far. The slide-out animation does not overlap the action bar as far as I can tell.

Comment: @RobertoNicbaAnićBanić It looks similar, but 1) I'm getting warnings, not errors, so maybe a different level of severity entirely, 2) This is coming directly from default Android Studio setup, so not from my own code, 3) this seems related to layout resources exclusively

Comment: Okay. Perhaps you are using honeycomb-008 or newer with an older OS? Resolve errors are usually because of a mismatch of old operating systems with newer themes

Comment: Should have clarified in the OP. will fix. Running Kitkat on Galaxy S3. Project is set to minSDK 15 targeting 21.

Comment: Scott, does your project use, or reference other libraries like "google play services" library ? I have similar errors.

Answer (score 9):

I would like to add on top of what @Monte Creasor explained.
I have had the same issue and consulted [this bug report](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=91424) which basically says that the problem might be caused by com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3, on of the main dependencies required to use Android's new Layout capabilities.
Try going back to the v7:20.0.0, this should solve the issue as it did for me and this bug report writer.

Actually all you have to change is in the app `build.gradle` the line:

`compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'`  or whatever later version you have

to

`compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:20.0.0'`

Comment: Doing this you will get: `This support library should not use a lower version (20) than the targetVersion (21)`, if your targetSDK version is 21.

Comment: Doing this gave me this in logcat, but got rid of the other errors: `OpenGLRenderer﹕ GL_INVALID_OPERATION` on my Sony Xperia Z

Answer (score 2):

These errors occur when you run android studio 1.0 using the sliding drawer sample WITHOUT adding any additional code and using all the defaults the project creation wizard offers. So it would seem to be an Android Studio problem and not a developer coding error.

Comment: That's interesting.  Do you have any links or bug reports on this? I wonder who else has seen this.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, also I wasn't able to get my ListFragment scrollable. Used v4 support library 21.0.3 before and upgraded to 22.0.0.

This fixed my problems!

Comment: I am using 22.0.0 version, it is still exist.

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently going through my logs generated from using Sony's remote device lab, the same warning appears so it's not a Android Studio problem. I suspect its a problem with the ActionBar theme used during the development of the application.