# Android Recycle View LogCat: Could not find method

Tags: android, android-studio, android-support-library, android-recyclerview, logcat

I have use RecyclerView from Android Support Library. When run on Samsung Galaxy S2 with Android 4.1.2 (API 16), all work fine but in Logcat I see messages:

```
03-24 I/dalvikvm: DexOpt: illegal method access (call Landroid/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView$ViewHolder;.isUpdated ()Z from Lnet/mytest/TransactionsAdapter$TransactionsAdapterViewHolder;)
03-24 I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$ViewHolder.isUpdated, referenced from method net.mytest.TransactionsAdapter$TransactionsAdapterViewHolder.access$super
03-24 W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 16775: Landroid/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView$ViewHolder;.isUpdated ()Z
03-24 D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0031
03-24 I/dalvikvm: DexOpt: illegal method access (call Landroid/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView$ViewHolder;.flagRemovedAndOffsetPosition (IIZ)V from Lnet/mytest/TransactionsAdapter$TransactionsAdapterViewHolder;)
03-24 I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$ViewHolder.flagRemovedAndOffsetPosition, referenced from method net.mytest.TransactionsAdapter$TransactionsAdapterViewHolder.access$super
03-24 W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 16759: Landroid/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView$ViewHolder;.flagRemovedAndOffsetPosition (IIZ)V
03-24 D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0053
03-24 I/dalvikvm: DexOpt: illegal method access (call Landroid/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView$ViewHolder;.isRemoved ()Z from Lnet/mytest/TransactionsAdapter$TransactionsAdapterViewHolder;)
03-24 I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$ViewHolder.isRemoved, referenced from method net.mytest.TransactionsAdapter$TransactionsAdapterViewHolder.access$super
03-24 W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 16772: Landroid/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView$ViewHolder;.isRemoved ()Z
03-24 D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0058
03-24 I/dalvikvm: DexOpt: illegal method access (call Landroid/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView$ViewHolder;.clearPayload ()V from Lnet/mytest/TransactionsAdapter$TransactionsAdapterViewHolder;)
03-24 I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$ViewHolder.clearPayload, referenced from method net.mytest.TransactionsAdapter$TransactionsAdapterViewHolder.access$super
03-24 W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 16754: Landroid/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView$ViewHolder;.clearPayload ()V
03-24 D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x007c
03-24 I/dalvikvm: DexOpt: illegal method access (call Landroid/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView$ViewHolder;.isAdapterPositionUnknown ()Z from Lnet/mytest/TransactionsAdapter$TransactionsAdapterViewHolder;)
03-24 I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$ViewHolder.isAdapterPositionUnknown, referenced from method net.mytest.TransactionsAdapter$TransactionsAdapterViewHolder.access$super
03-24 W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 16768: Landroid/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView$ViewHolder;.isAdapterPositionUnknown ()Z
03-24 D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0086
03-24 I/dalvikvm: DexOpt: illegal method access (call Landroid/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView$ViewHolder;.offsetPosition (IZ)V from Lnet/mytest/TransactionsAdapter$TransactionsAdapterViewHolder;)
03-24 I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$ViewHolder.offsetPosition, referenced from method net.mytest.TransactionsAdapter$TransactionsAdapterViewHolder.access$super
03-24 W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 16777: Landroid/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView$ViewHolder;.offsetPosition (IZ)V
03-24 D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x00ad
03-24 I/dalvikvm: DexOpt: illegal method access (call Landroid/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView$ViewHolder;.shouldIgnore ()Z from Lnet/mytest/TransactionsAdapter$TransactionsAdapterViewHolder;)
03-24 I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$ViewHolder.shouldIgnore, referenced from method net.mytest.TransactionsAdapter$TransactionsAdapterViewHolder.access$super
03-24 W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 16786: Landroid/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView$ViewHolder;.shouldIgnore ()Z
03-24 D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x00b9
03-24 I/dalvikvm: DexOpt: illegal method access (call Landroid/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView$ViewHolder;.setFlags (II)V from Lnet/mytest/TransactionsAdapter$TransactionsAdapterViewHolder;)
03-24 I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$ViewHolder.setFlags, referenced from method net.mytest.TransactionsAdapter$TransactionsAdapterViewHolder.access$super
03-24 W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 16782: Landroid/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView$ViewHolder;.setFlags (II)V
03-24 D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x00d4
03-24 I/dalvikvm: DexOpt: illegal method access (call Landroid/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView$ViewHolder;.addChangePayload (Ljava/lang/Object;)V from Lnet/mytest/TransactionsAdapter$TransactionsAdapterViewHolder;)
03-24 I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$ViewHolder.addChangePayload, referenced from method net.mytest.TransactionsAdapter$TransactionsAdapterViewHolder.access$super
03-24 W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 16751: Landroid/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView$ViewHolder;.addChangePayload (Ljava/lang/Object;)V
03-24 D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x00dc
```

Should I worry about this messages?

Answer (score 0):

Look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/18600156/1852441

Basically, you aren't calling the correct method. You will have to call the corresponding "support" method.

eg. calling getActionBar() from v14 instead of getSupportActionBar() from v7 will cause this issue.

**Make sure you call the support methods and this error will go away.**