# Menu won't show in navigation bar

Tags: android, navigationbar, options-menu

im trying to add a (+) icon on right of navigation bar in android, and then launch a new intent when clicked, but i can't seem to make it work, it's showing me the left icon to open/close the drawer, but the right icon is nowhere to be found.

Can anyone give me a hand on why its not working? im loosing my mind here...

The navigation bar looks like this, there's enough room for the right side
[image: Navigation bar]

ActivityHome.java

```
package com.roneskinder.x111.activity.fragment;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.DialogInterface.OnDismissListener;
import android.content.DialogInterface.OnKeyListener;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager.NameNotFoundException;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.roneskinder.x111.PagerSlidingTabStrip;
import com.roneskinder.x111.R;
import com.roneskinder.x111.adapter.MenuAdapter;
import com.roneskinder.x111.config.AppConfig;
import com.roneskinder.x111.manager.ResourcesContentManager;
import com.roneskinder.x111.model.NavDrawerItem;
import com.roneskinder.x111.util.AppUtils;

public class ActivityHome extends ActionBarActivity {
    private Context mContext;
    DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView mDrawerList;
    private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;
    private CharSequence mTitle;
    private String[] navMenuTitles;
    private FragmentManager mFragmentManager;
    private Fragment mFragment;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
    private TypedArray navMenuIcons;
    private ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> mNavDrawerItems;
    private MenuAdapter menuAdapter;
    private Dialog mCustomDialog;
    private RelativeLayout mAdsView;

    protected static String TAG = ActivityHome.class.toString();
    protected static EditText nameList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mContext = ActivityHome.this;
        showNavigationSlider();
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            selectItem(0);
        }
        // Init Ads
        // initAds();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        setTheme();
    }

    /**
     * Method to show navigation drawer
     */
    private void showNavigationSlider() {
        if (mDrawerLayout == null) {
            // enable ActionBar app icon to behave as action to toggle nav drawer
            getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
            mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();
            navMenuTitles = getResources().getStringArray(
                    R.array.nav_drawer_items);
            navMenuIcons = getResources().obtainTypedArray(
                    R.array.nav_drawer_icons);
            mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
            mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);
            mNavDrawerItems = new ArrayList<NavDrawerItem>();
            mNavDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[0],
                    navMenuIcons.getResourceId(0, -1)));
            mNavDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[1],
                    navMenuIcons.getResourceId(1, -1)));
            mNavDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[2],
                    navMenuIcons.getResourceId(2, -1)));
            mNavDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[3],
                    navMenuIcons.getResourceId(3, -1)));
            mNavDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[4],
                    navMenuIcons.getResourceId(4, -1)));
            mNavDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[5],
                    navMenuIcons.getResourceId(5, -1)));
            mNavDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[6],
                    navMenuIcons.getResourceId(6, -1)));
            navMenuIcons.recycle();
            mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new SlideMenuClickListener());
            menuAdapter = new MenuAdapter(ActivityHome.this);
            menuAdapter.setList(mNavDrawerItems);
            mDrawerList.setAdapter(menuAdapter);

            mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle
                    (
                    this,                  /* host Activity */
                    mDrawerLayout,         /* DrawerLayout object */
                    R.drawable.ic_drawer,  /* nav drawer image to replace 'Up' caret */
                    R.string.app_name,  /* "open drawer" description for accessibility */
                    R.string.app_name  /* "close drawer" description for accessibility */
                    ) {
                public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                    getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                    invalidateOptionsMenu();
                }

                public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                    getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
                    invalidateOptionsMenu();
                }
            };
            mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
        mTitle = title;
        getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
    }

    /**
     * When using the ActionBarDrawerToggle, you must call it during
     * onPostCreate() and onConfigurationChanged()...
     */
    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
        setTheme();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Here im inflating my menu options
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.new_list, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    /* Called whenever we call invalidateOptionsMenu() */
    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // If the nav drawer is open, hide action items related to the content view
        boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
        // here im setting its visibility to true/false depending on the drawer position
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_new_list).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        switch (item.getItemId()) {

        case android.R.id.home: {
            if (mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList)) {
                mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
            } else {
                mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(mDrawerList);
            }
            break;
        }
        // here im adding a click event in the button
        case R.id.action_new_list:
            aboutClicked();
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * Slide menu item click listener
     * */
    private class SlideMenuClickListener implements
            ListView.OnItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {
            onItemClickListerner(position);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Display selected navigation drawer list item
     * */
    private void onItemClickListerner(int position) {
        Intent intent = null;
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            //intent = new Intent(mContext, ActivitySettings.class);
            //startActivity(intent);
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
            break;
        case 1:
            //intent = new Intent(mContext, ActivityTheme.class);
            //startActivity(intent);
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
            break;
        case 2:
            //updateClicked();
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
            break;
        case 3:
            //moreAppClicked();
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
            break;
        case 4:
            //shareClicked(getString(R.string.share_subject),TabsApplication.getAppUrl());
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
            break;
        case 5:
            //rateAppClicked();
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
            break;
        case 6:
            newListClicked();
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
            break;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Method to check for updated app.
     */
    private void updateClicked() {
        try {
            startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                    Uri.parse("market://details?id="
                            + mContext.getPackageName())));
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
            startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                    Uri.parse("http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id="
                            + mContext.getPackageName())));
        }
    }

    /**
     * Method to rate the app.
     */
    private void rateAppClicked() {
        try {
            startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                    Uri.parse("market://details?id="
                            + mContext.getPackageName())));
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
            startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                    Uri.parse("http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id="
                            + mContext.getPackageName())));
        }
    }

    /**
     * Method to share app via different available share apps
     */
    private void shareClicked(String subject, String text) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intent.setType("text/plain");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, text);
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent,
                getString(R.string.share_via)));
    }

    /**
     * Method to Show more apps from Developer
     */
    private void moreAppClicked() {
        try {
            startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(String
                    .format("market://search?q=pub:%s",
                            AppConfig.PLAYSTORE_ACCOUNT_NAME))));
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
            startActivity(new Intent(
                    Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                    Uri.parse(String
                            .format("https://play.google.com/store/apps/developer?id=%s&hl=en",
                                    AppConfig.PLAYSTORE_ACCOUNT_NAME))));
        }
    }

    /**
     * Method to show about
     */
    private void aboutClicked() {
        try {
            String appname = null;
            appname = getString(R.string.app_name_message) + " "
                    + getString(R.string.app_name) + "" + "\n\n";
            String appversion = getString(R.string.app_version)
                    + " "
                    + mContext.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
                            mContext.getPackageName(),
                            PackageInfo.CONTENTS_FILE_DESCRIPTOR).versionCode
                    + "\n\n";
            String name = getString(R.string.response_message);

            showAboutCustomDialog(getString(R.string.about), appname
                    + appversion + name, getString(R.string.ok),
                    getString(R.string.cancel), true);
        } catch (NameNotFoundException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Method to show custom dialog.
     * 
     * @param title
     * @param message
     * @param okText
     * @param cancelText
     * @param singleButtonEnabled
     */
    private void showAboutCustomDialog(String title, String message,
            String okText, String cancelText, boolean singleButtonEnabled) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.about_dialog_view, null);
        RelativeLayout titlebarView = (RelativeLayout) dialogView
                .findViewById(R.id.title_bar_view);
        titlebarView.setBackgroundColor(ResourcesContentManager.getInstance()
                .getTitleBarColor(mContext, -1));
        Button okButton = (Button) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.ok_button);
        Button cancelButton = (Button) dialogView
                .findViewById(R.id.cancel_button);
        okButton.setBackgroundResource(ResourcesContentManager.getInstance()
                .getButtonBackgroundResource(mContext, -1));
        okButton.setTextAppearance(mContext, ResourcesContentManager
                .getInstance().getButtonTextStyle(mContext, -1));
        cancelButton.setBackgroundResource(ResourcesContentManager
                .getInstance().getButtonBackgroundResource(mContext, -1));
        cancelButton.setTextAppearance(mContext, ResourcesContentManager
                .getInstance().getButtonTextStyle(mContext, -1));
        TextView titleTextview = (TextView) dialogView
                .findViewById(R.id.title_textview);
        TextView messageTextview = (TextView) dialogView
                .findViewById(R.id.message_textview);
        TextView name = (TextView) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.email_textview);
        name.setText("test@test.com");
        if (mCustomDialog != null) {
            mCustomDialog.dismiss();
            mCustomDialog = null;
        }
        mCustomDialog = new Dialog(mContext,
                android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar);
        mCustomDialog.setContentView(dialogView);
        mCustomDialog.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {

            public boolean onKey(DialogInterface dialog, int keyCode,
                    KeyEvent event) {
                if (KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK == keyCode) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
        mCustomDialog.setOnDismissListener(new OnDismissListener() {

            public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
            }
        });

        mCustomDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);

        titleTextview.setText(title);
        messageTextview.setText(message);
        if (singleButtonEnabled) {
            okButton.setText(okText);
            cancelButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {
            okButton.setText(okText);
            cancelButton.setText(cancelText);
        }

        /**
         * Listener for OK button click.
         */
        okButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                mCustomDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        /**
         * Listener for Cancel button click.
         */
        cancelButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                mCustomDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        mCustomDialog.show();
    }

    /**
     * Method to create new list
     */
    private void newListClicked() {
        showCreateListDialog("Nueva lista de compras", "Crear", getString(R.string.cancel), false);
    }

    /**
     * Method to create new list dialog
     * 
     * @param title
     * @param message
     * @param okText
     * @param cancelText
     * @param singleButtonEnabled
     */
    private void showCreateListDialog(String title,
            String okText, String cancelText, boolean singleButtonEnabled) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.new_list_dialog_view, null);

        RelativeLayout titlebarView = (RelativeLayout) dialogView
                .findViewById(R.id.title_bar_view);
        titlebarView.setBackgroundColor(ResourcesContentManager.getInstance()
                .getTitleBarColor(mContext, -1));
        Button okButton = (Button) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.ok_button);
        Button cancelButton = (Button) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.cancel_button);
        okButton.setBackgroundResource(ResourcesContentManager.getInstance().getButtonBackgroundResource(mContext, -1));
        okButton.setTextAppearance(mContext, ResourcesContentManager.getInstance().getButtonTextStyle(mContext, -1));
        cancelButton.setBackgroundResource(ResourcesContentManager.getInstance().getButtonBackgroundResource(mContext, -1));
        cancelButton.setTextAppearance(mContext, ResourcesContentManager.getInstance().getButtonTextStyle(mContext, -1));
        TextView titleTextview = (TextView) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.title_textview);

        nameList = (EditText) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.list_name);
        if (mCustomDialog != null) {
            mCustomDialog.dismiss();
            mCustomDialog = null;
        }
        mCustomDialog = new Dialog(mContext,android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar);
        mCustomDialog.setContentView(dialogView);
        mCustomDialog.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {

            public boolean onKey(DialogInterface dialog, int keyCode,
                    KeyEvent event) {
                if (KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK == keyCode) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
        mCustomDialog.setOnDismissListener(new OnDismissListener() {

            public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
            }
        });

        mCustomDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);

        titleTextview.setText(title);
        if (singleButtonEnabled) {
            okButton.setText(okText);
            cancelButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {
            okButton.setText(okText);
            cancelButton.setText(cancelText);
        }

        /**
         * Listener for OK button click.
         */
        okButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // if list has valid name, save
                String name = nameList.getText().toString();
                if(!name.matches("")){
                    Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, ActivityAddProductsToList.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    mCustomDialog.dismiss();
                }else{
                    AppUtils.showToast(mContext, "Por favor ingrese el nombre de la nueva lista");
                }

            }
        });

        /**
         * Listener for Cancel button click.
         */
        cancelButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                mCustomDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        mCustomDialog.show();
    }

    private void selectItem(int position) {

        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.content,
                            FragmentPageSlidingTabStrip.newInstance(),
                            FragmentPageSlidingTabStrip.TAG).commit();
            break;
        default:

            // mFragment = new PlanetFragment();
            // Bundle args = new Bundle();
            // args.putInt(PlanetFragment.ARG_PLANET_NUMBER, position);
            // mFragment.setArguments(args);
            //
            // getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            // .add(R.id.content, mFragment).commit();
            break;
        }

        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        if (mContext != null) {
            if (mCustomDialog != null) {
                mCustomDialog.dismiss();
                mCustomDialog = null;
            }
            mDrawerList = null;
            mDrawerTitle = null;
            mTitle = null;
            navMenuTitles = null;
            mFragmentManager = null;
            mFragment = null;
            mDrawerLayout = null;
            mDrawerToggle = null;
            mContext = null;
            super.onDestroy();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Method to set themes backgrounds
     */
    private void setTheme() {
        int actionBarTitleId = Resources.getSystem().getIdentifier(
                "action_bar_title", "id", "android");
        if (actionBarTitleId > 0) {
            TextView title = (TextView) findViewById(actionBarTitleId);
            title.setTextAppearance(mContext, R.style.ActionBarTitleTextStyle);
        }
        getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(
                new ColorDrawable(ResourcesContentManager.getInstance()
                        .getTitleBarColor(mContext, -1)));
        mDrawerList.setBackgroundColor(ResourcesContentManager.getInstance()
                .getScreenBgColor(mContext, -1));
        PagerSlidingTabStrip tabStrip = (PagerSlidingTabStrip) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabStrip.setIndicatorColor(ResourcesContentManager.getInstance()
                .getTitleBarColor(mContext, -1));
    }

    /**
     * Method to inits the ads banner view
     */
    /*
    private void initAds() {
        if (mAdsView == null) {
            mAdsView = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.bottom_ads_view);
        }
        if (AppConfig.BANNER_ADS_ENABLED) {
            mAdsView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            AppUtils.addAdsBannerView(ActivityHome.this, mAdsView);
        } else {
            mAdsView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }
    */
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_view"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/bottom_ads_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/content"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_above="@id/bottom_ads_view" >
        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <!-- The navigation drawer -->

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/slider_width"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@color/slider_bg_color"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@color/slider_divider_color"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

new_list.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/action_new_list"
          android:icon="@drawable/action_search"
          android:title="@string/action_new_list"
          android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText" />
</menu>
```

Comment: I also tried to change the showAsAction value to android:showAsAction="always, also no luck

Comment: Can you try this in onCreate()? `ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();` `actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);`

Comment: Its already there, line 98 in ActivityHome.java `getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);`

Comment: @RonEskinder, see this [Action Bar Support - Menu show icon]( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18099221/action-bar-not-showing-action-view-icons)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change following line in `onCreateOptionsMenu`

```
return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
```

to

```
return true;
```

Comment: Can you inherit from `Activity` instead of `ActionbarActivity` and let me know if it works?

Comment: It worked! but i lost my tabs because its having a conflict with `getSupportFragmentManager()
     .beginTransaction()
     .add(R.id.content,
       FragmentPageSlidingTabStrip.newInstance(),
       FragmentPageSlidingTabStrip.TAG).commit();`

Comment: I guess thats a different question :)

Comment: @RonEskinder You should be able to inherit from FragmentActivity and do both.

Answer (score -1):

The id of your menu item is the same name as the string (action_new_list). I'd try changing that to see if there's a collision.
2. Add a titleCondensed attribute, as [that's all that will show in your Options Menu.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Menu.html)

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/action_new_list"
          android:icon="@drawable/action_search"
          android:title="@string/action_new_list"
          android:titleCondensed="@string/new_string"
          android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText" />
</menu>
```

Comment: the item *action_new_list* is an item from menu *new_list*, first I reference the menu item and then inflate the menu.

Comment: @RonEskinder Is the search icon in your _new_list_ menu if you click to expand?

Comment: I can't click on anything on the right side because there is no icons there, only on le left, the icon to open/close drawer.

Comment: @RonEskinder Check edits to my answer. You should still be seeing the Options Menu, and I'm thinking one of those solutions is the reason you're not.

Comment: Tried the android:titleCondensed attribute, no luck, the title was small already though, i updated my question with an image of the navigation bar.