# NullPointerException on MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem)

Tags: android, eclipse, android-actionbar-compat

- For Android 2.3.3 (or any below API 16) my app works without showing any error.
- For Android 4.1 devices (API 16) and higher I get this error (app has min API Level 10):
  `java.lang.NullPointerException E/AndroidRuntime(1066): at at.kopp.huettenapp.MasterActivity.onCreateOptionsMenu(MasterActivity.java:347)`

**manifest.xml**

```
<activity
android:name="at.kopp.huettenapp.MasterActivity"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar" >
...`
```

**menu.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<item 
      android:id="@+id/action_search"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_2_action_search"
      android:title="Suche"
      app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
      app:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView" />
```

**MasterActivity.java**

```
public class MasterActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements HutList.Callbacks, OnQueryTextListener, OnCloseListener {
...
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.activity_master_actions, menu);

    // Associate searchable configuration with the SearchView
    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem);
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName())); // << line 347
    // set id to save state
    searchView.setId(R.id.action_search_widget);

    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
    searchView.setOnCloseListener(this);

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

**Full error stack from LogCat**

```
02-21 17:28:58.703: W/SupportMenuInflater(1066): Cannot instantiate class: android.app.SearchView
02-21 17:28:58.703: W/SupportMenuInflater(1066): java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.app.SearchView" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/at.kopp.huettenapp-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/at.kopp.huettenapp-1, /system/lib]]
02-21 17:28:58.703: W/SupportMenuInflater(1066):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:53)
02-21 17:28:58.703: W/SupportMenuInflater(1066):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
02-21 17:28:58.703: W/SupportMenuInflater(1066):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
02-21 17:28:58.703: W/SupportMenuInflater(1066):    at android.support.v7.internal.view.SupportMenuInflater$MenuState.newInstance(SupportMenuInflater.java:480)
02-21 17:28:58.703: W/SupportMenuInflater(1066):    at android.support.v7.internal.view.SupportMenuInflater$MenuState.setItem(SupportMenuInflater.java:441)
02-21 17:28:58.703: W/SupportMenuInflater(1066):    at android.support.v7.internal.view.SupportMenuInflater$MenuState.addItem(SupportMenuInflater.java:462)
02-21 17:28:58.703: W/SupportMenuInflater(1066):    at android.support.v7.internal.view.SupportMenuInflater.parseMenu(SupportMenuInflater.java:196)
02-21 17:28:58.703: W/SupportMenuInflater(1066):    at android.support.v7.internal.view.SupportMenuInflater.inflate(SupportMenuInflater.java:118)
02-21 17:28:58.703: W/SupportMenuInflater(1066):    at at.kopp.huettenapp.MasterActivity.onCreateOptionsMenu(MasterActivity.java:340)
02-21 17:28:58.703: W/SupportMenuInflater(1066):    at android.app.Activity.onCreatePanelMenu(Activity.java:2504)
02-21 17:28:58.703: W/SupportMenuInflater(1066):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreatePanelMenu(FragmentActivity.java:224)
02-21 17:28:58.703: W/SupportMenuInflater(1066):    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.superOnCreatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivity.java:232)
02-21 17:28:58.703: W/SupportMenuInflater(1066):    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.onCreatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:147)
02-21 17:28:58.703: W/SupportMenuInflater(1066):    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.onCreatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivity.java:199)
02-21 17:28:58.703: W/SupportMenuInflater(1066):    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS$WindowCallbackWrapper.onCreatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:285)
      ...
02-21 17:28:58.943: E/AndroidRuntime(1066): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-21 17:28:58.943: E/AndroidRuntime(1066): java.lang.NullPointerException
02-21 17:28:58.943: E/AndroidRuntime(1066):     at at.kopp.huettenapp.MasterActivity.onCreateOptionsMenu(MasterActivity.java:347)
02-21 17:28:58.943: E/AndroidRuntime(1066):     at android.app.Activity.onCreatePanelMenu(Activity.java:2504)
02-21 17:28:58.943: E/AndroidRuntime(1066):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreatePanelMenu(FragmentActivity.java:224)
02-21 17:28:58.943: E/AndroidRuntime(1066):     at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.superOnCreatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivity.java:232)
02-21 17:28:58.943: E/AndroidRuntime(1066):     at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.onCreatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:147)
02-21 17:28:58.943: E/AndroidRuntime(1066):     at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.onCreatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivity.java:199)
02-21 17:28:58.943: E/AndroidRuntime(1066):     at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS$WindowCallbackWrapper.onCreatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:285)
02-21 17:28:58.943: E/AndroidRuntime(1066):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.preparePanel(PhoneWindow.java:413)
02-21 17:28:58.943: E/AndroidRuntime(1066):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.doInvalidatePanelMenu(PhoneWindow.java:775)
02-21 17:28:58.943: E/AndroidRuntime(1066):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$1.run(PhoneWindow.java:198)
02-21 17:28:58.943: E/AndroidRuntime(1066):     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
02-21 17:28:58.943: E/AndroidRuntime(1066):     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
02-21 17:28:58.943: E/AndroidRuntime(1066):     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:531)
02-21 17:28:58.943: E/AndroidRuntime(1066):     at           android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
02-21 17:28:58.943: E/AndroidRuntime(1066):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
02-21 17:28:58.943: E/AndroidRuntime(1066):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-21 17:28:58.943: E/AndroidRuntime(1066):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-21 17:28:58.943: E/AndroidRuntime(1066):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
02-21 17:28:58.943: E/AndroidRuntime(1066):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-21 17:28:58.943: E/AndroidRuntime(1066):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
02-21 17:28:58.943: E/AndroidRuntime(1066):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
02-21 17:28:58.943: E/AndroidRuntime(1066):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
02-21 17:28:58.943: E/AndroidRuntime(1066):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! It is easier to get a good answer when you post an explicit question in your question text. For this, I assume it is something along the lines of "How do I fix this execption?" and if possible, add what you have already done to try to fix the problem

Comment: This answer may also help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6213746/how-can-i-add-a-searchview-to-my-android-app